# why i can't run my test cases in ServiceTestCase?

Tags: android, servicetestcase

Here's my service test code.

```
public class BackgroundTaskServiceTest extends ServiceTestCase<BackgroundTaskService> {

public BackgroundTaskServiceTest(Class<BackgroundTaskService> serviceClass) {
    super(serviceClass);
}

public BackgroundTaskServiceTest() {
    super(BackgroundTaskService.class);
}

@SmallTest
public void startServiceTest() {
    assertEquals(0, 1);
}

@Override
public void setUp() {
    try {
        super.setUp();
        System.err.println("setup called");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
public void tearDown() {
    try {
        System.err.println("teardown called");
        super.tearDown();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

I right-click the project name and select "Run as Android Junit Test". The `setUp` and `tearDown` callbacks are called properly , but my `startServiceTest` is never run.

This is the screen shot of test results:

[image]

And another strange thing is that the "setup called" and "teardown called" both appear twice.

So anyone knows why? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think the way that the ADT plugin for Android JUnit works, you need to name your tests starting with 'test', e.g.:

```
public void testStartService() {
    assertEquals(0, 1);
}
```

Try that and see if it runs.